# Question about hierachy Views design in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad

If I've a hierarchy of Views to display in my window (let's say a grid and each grid cell is a UIView with Image + caption), how should I implement it without breaking the MVC design pattern ?

Should I create a MVC for each cell, and then how can I add them to the main MCV and related it to the main view ?

Or should I just create a cell View and add it to the main view with addSubView method ?

Thanks

ps. I've found this example, is this correct ? Do I need to create a controller and then add its view to the mainView and release the controller ?

```
SimpleViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[mainView addSubview:viewController.view];
[viewController release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

> Model objects encapsulate the data specific to an application and define the logic and computation that manipulate and process that data...
>
> A view object is an object in an application that users can see...
>
> A controller object acts as an intermediary between one or more of an application’s view objects and one or more of its model objects. Controller objects are thus a conduit through which view objects learn about changes in model objects and vice versa. Controller objects can also perform setup and coordinating tasks for an application and manage the life cycles of other objects...

If you just want to display some content then all you need are views, no need for models or controllers if there's nothing to model and no need to have a controller manage those views.

Even if those views are build from some models there no need to necessarily give each one its own controller object. Instead you might have a grid view with a "datasource" delegate which it can ask for the cells to display, much like UITableView.

What do your grid cells represent? Does it make sense to have a model object capture view-independent behavior and state for that data?

---

> ps. I've found this example, is this correct ? Do I need to create a controller and then add its view to the mainView and release the controller ?

Do not do this, that's a misuse of UIViewController and likely to lead to confusion. If you just want a view object then just create the view object. You can load objects from a nib without creating extra controller object like that. Look at NSBundle or UINib for alternate ways to load objects from nib files.